# Jquery Piping Multiple results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have three methods
`loadMeta`, `loadData`, and `renderList`.

`loadMeta` pipes its result to `loadData`.  LoadData uses the meta to get its results;

Then I need to to get the result from `loadMeta` and `loadData` and pass them both to `renderList`.  But I don't know how to get both sets of results, I just end up with the result from `loadData`.

This is (basically) what i'm trying to do:

```
$.when(loadMeta().pipe(loadData)).then(function(){ renderList(metaResult, dataResult); } );
```

is it possible to do it inline or do I need to break the statements up?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? `pipe` is just a non-standard alias for `then` in recent versions

Comment: I'm using 1.7.2 (I must admit I struggle to differentiate between then and pipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the easiest if your `loadData` function would return both results.

A simple function to let the result be an object containing both results would need an additional `then` (`pipe`):

```
loadMeta().then(function(metaResult) {
    return loadData(metaResult).then(function(dataResult) {
        return {meta:metaResult, data:dataResult};
    });
}).done(function(result) {
    renderList(result.meta, result.data);
});
```

Or, you merge them to a resolve callback with just the right signature for `renderList`:

```
loadMeta().then(function(metaResult) {
    return loadData(metaResult).then(function(dataResult) {
        return new $.Deferred().resolve(metaResult, dataResult);
    });
}).done(renderList);
```

Or, as you suggested, we might break the statement and add an additional callback to cache the `metaResult`:

```
var metaResult;
loadMeta().done(function(result) {
    metaResult = result;
}).then(loadData).done(function(dataResult) {
   renderList(metaResult, dataResult);
});
```

This might be the easiest to understand.